# ERROR: "(" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting an indentifier

Tags: mysql, triggers

ERROR STATEMENT:

> CALCULATE_LATE_FEE_AND_TAX(:NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME, :NEW.RET_DT_TIME,
> :NEW.REG_NUM,:NEW.AMOUNT, totalLateFee, totalTax)

THE WHOLE CODE IS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER GENERATE_BILLING
AFTER
UPDATE
    ON BOOKING_DETAILS FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF (
        IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME), 'NULL') <> 'NULL'
        AND NEW.BOOKING_STATUS = 'R'
    ) THEN BEGIN DECLARE lastBillId VARCHAR(45);DECLARE newBillId VARCHAR(45);DECLARE discountAmt DECIMAL(19, 4);DECLARE totalLateFee VARCHAR(4000);DECLARE totalTax DECIMAL(19, 4);DECLARE totalAmountBeforeDiscount DECIMAL(19, 4);DECLARE finalAmount DECIMAL(19, 4);
SELECT
    BILL_ID INTO lastBillId
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            BILL_ID,
            ROWNUM AS RN
        FROM
            BILLING_DETAILS
    )
WHERE
    RN = (
        SELECT
            MAX(ROWNUM)
        FROM
            BILLING_DETAILS
    );
SET
    newBillId = CONCAT(
        'BL',
        IFNULL(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(lastBillId, 3)) + 1), '')
    );CALCULATE_LATE_FEE_AND_TAX(
        NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME,
        NEW.RET_DT_TIME,
        NEW.REG_NUM,
        NEW.AMOUNT,
        totalLateFee,
        totalTax
    );
SET
    totalAmountBeforeDiscount = NEW.AMOUNT + totalLateFee + totalTax;CALCULATE_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT(
        NEW.DL_NUM,
        totalAmountBeforeDiscount,
        NEW.DISCOUNT_CODE,
        discountAmt
    );
SET
    finalAmount = totalAmountBeforeDiscount - discountAmt;
INSERT INTO
    BILLING_DETAILS (
        BILL_ID,
        BILL_DATE,
        BILL_STATUS,
        DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
        TOTAL_AMOUNT,
        TAX_AMOUNT,
        BOOKING_ID,
        TOTAL_LATE_FEE
    )
VALUES
    (
        newBillId,
        str_to_date(SYSDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d'),
        'P',
        discountAmt,
        finalAmount,
        totalTax,
        NEW.BOOKING_ID,
        totalLateFee
    );
END;
```

Comment: :NEW is Oracle/pl-sql syntax if this is really mysql drop the colon(s). Also include the significant parts of the trigger including the create statement and the function CALCULATE_LATE_FEE_AND_TAX invocation code.

Comment: I have tried that too still it is not working. Let me send the whole trigger code. Kindly look into it.

Comment: You cannot invoke a function in that way see manual for how you can invoke.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html and you aren't capturing the return value. Plus there is much else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors including the function invocation and the missing end and missing end if;

I have no idea what your trigger is supposed to do but this synataxes.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS T;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER T AFTER UPDATE ON BOOKING_DETAILS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF(IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME), 'NULL') <> 'NULL' AND NEW.BOOKING_STATUS = 'R') THEN 
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE lastBillId VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE newBillId VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE discountAmt DECIMAL(19, 4);
    DECLARE totalLateFee VARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE totalTax DECIMAL(19, 4);
    DECLARE totalAmountBeforeDiscount DECIMAL(19, 4);
    DECLARE finalAmount DECIMAL(19, 4);
    SELECT BILL_ID INTO lastBillId
    FROM
    (SELECT BILL_ID,
            ROWNUM AS RN
      FROM BILLING_DETAILS
     ) s
    WHERE
    RN = (SELECT
            MAX(ROWNUM)
          FROM BILLING_DETAILS
         );
    SET newBillId = CONCAT('BL',IFNULL(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(lastBillId, 3)) + 1), ''));
    
    select CALCULATE_LATE_FEE_AND_TAX(
        NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME,
        NEW.RET_DT_TIME,
        NEW.REG_NUM,
        NEW.AMOUNT,
        totalLateFee,
        totalTax
    ) into @a;
    
    SET totalAmountBeforeDiscount = NEW.AMOUNT + totalLateFee + totalTax;
    
    select CALCULATE_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT(
        NEW.DL_NUM,
        totalAmountBeforeDiscount,
        NEW.DISCOUNT_CODE,
        discountAmt
    ) into @a;
    
    sET finalAmount = totalAmountBeforeDiscount - discountAmt;
    
    INSERT INTO
    BILLING_DETAILS (
        BILL_ID,
        BILL_DATE,
        BILL_STATUS,
        DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
        TOTAL_AMOUNT,
        TAX_AMOUNT,
        BOOKING_ID,
        TOTAL_LATE_FEE
    )
    VALUES
    (
        newBillId,
        str_to_date(sysdate(), '%Y-%m-%d'),
        'P',
        discountAmt,
        finalAmount,
        totalTax,
        NEW.BOOKING_ID,
        totalLateFee
    );
    
   end;
end if;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

BTW to_char is oracle not mysql and is supect sysdate is too.